# How to read through a CSV then post a bulk API call in Python

Tags: python, json, api, csv

I was able to read through a CSV, populate a JSON object then post an "update.user" call to an endpont, but I can't figure out how to do the same in bulk (50 records at a time).

This is an example of the Json Body it wants:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "email": "string",
      "dataFields": {},
      "userId": "string",
      "preferUserId": true,
      "mergeNestedObjects": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my code for posting updates user by user. How can I do this in bulk for 50 users at a time?

```
import requests
import json
import csv
import pdb

with open('john2.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_file = csv.reader(csv_file)

    next(csv_file)

    for line in csv_file :
        #print(line[2])


        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",
                  "Accept": "application/json"
                   }

        body = {"email": line[2],
                "dataFields": {"firstName": line[0],
                               "lastName" : line[1],
                               "favoriteTomatoe" : line[3],
                               "totalTomatoOrders" : line[4],
                               "daysSinceLastOrder" : line[5],
                               "zip" : line[6],
                               "phoneNumber" : line[7],
                               "age" : line[8],
                               "streetAddress" : line[9],
                               "city" : line[10],
                               "state" : line[11],
                               "customMessageOne" : line[12],
                               "gender" : line[13]
                               }
                }

body = json.dumps(body) 

res = requests.request("POST", 
        "https://api.iterable.com/api/users/update?apiKey="key"", 
        headers=headers, data=body)
print(res.url + "\n" + str(res.status_code) + res.text)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You API key has been leaked to the internet. Please invalidate it with your platform and create a new one.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here you want to add a limit variable with the amount of calls you want to make. Once done, then you have a few options.

You can use a for loop count or a while loop (e.g. for i in range(0, limit):) where for each row you add the row to a global list.

Once we hit the limit of that list, we want to send that payload to the endpoint and empty the list.

(Will update code base)

```
limit = 50
curVal = 0
user_list = []

with open('john2.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_file = csv.reader(csv_file)

    next(csv_file)

    for line in csv_file :
        user_list.append({"email": line[2],
           "dataFields": {...}
        })
        if curVal == limit:
            body = json.dumps(user_list)
            res = requests.request("POST", 
                "https://api.iterable.com/api/users/update?apiKey="key"", 
                headers=headers, data=body)
            curVal = 0
            user_list = []
        else:
            curVal++
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks so much! That was super helpful. I think that I'm getting closer. I was getting a  error with "curVal++" so I updated it to "curVal = curVal + 1"

Now the issue is that I'm getting 404...

Comment: My bad, this was all inline edited. Essentially its just creating a batch process that you then send. For small jobs (10,000 rows) I find this is enough. For more, might want to look at a specialised library. But glad I could help.

Comment: No problem! Thanks a bunch, I really appreciate it. I'm sure I can get it from here

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this snippet:

```
  user_list = get_users() # ['user_1', 'user_2', ... , 'user_n']
  TOTAL_USERS = len(user_list)
  session = requests.Session()
  try:
    # Add logic to read each user from user_list, then modify for loop below.
    for user in user_list:
      print("Testing user {}").format(user)
      response = session.post(
        URL,
        data=predict_request)
      response.raise_for_status()
      total_time += response.elapsed.total_seconds()
    print('Num requests: {} Avg latency: {} ms'.format(TOTAL_USERS, (
      total_time * 1000) / TOTAL_USERS))
    # You may do something here for each request
  except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    logging.exception(err)
    if err.response.status_code == 400:
      logging.exception('Server error %s', URL)
      return
    if err.response.status_code == 404:
      logging.exception('Page not found %s', URL)
```

You only need to read from a list of users and replace the for loop with each user.

Is taken from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ml-on-gcp/blob/master/dlvm/nvidia/inference.py), I also recommend you to take a look at [retry](https://github.com/invl/retry) library.